# How to push/ show a view controller up in the view hierarchy from the app delegate and keep the navigation structure

Tags: ios, swift

I've got this view hierarchy in my app.

[image]

Tab bar => item 1 is collection view embedded in a navigation controller.
Item 2 is a split view controller

The split view controller => master (table view controller) embedded in a navigation controller.
Detail (table view controller [**the target**]) embedded in a navigation controller and has a child table view controller

Based on receiving push notifications, I would like to show [**the target**] table view controller that is way above in the view hierarchy (as depicted in the image) and still keep the same view structure/ hierarchy so that a user may still navigate throughout the app. So the trick of 
`window?.rootViewController = targetViewController` is no good.

I've added the below code but it crashes the app with error 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let targetController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("targetController") as! TargetTableViewController
let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
let splitController = tabBarController.viewControllers!.last as! UISplitViewController
let navController2 = splitController.viewControllers.last as! UINavigationController

navController2.popToViewController(targetController, animated: true)
```

Comment: You can to call segue programmatically using `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Comment: from the app delegate `applicationDidLaunchWithOptions`? It does nothing... The app opens up normally at the initial view.

Comment: Ahmed, you have to root your tabbarcontroller in a navigationcontroller to get what you want. it's giving you this error because there is no rootviewcontroller for the tabbarcontroller .. a tabbarcontroller is not a navigationcontroller, it's a class of UIViewController is like a brother to UINavigationController, tabbarcontrollers are NOT navigationCointrollers even though they allow navigation.

Comment: OK. Thanks @Larcerax.